# What is the equivelant of 1 teaspoon of vanilla extract in Organic Vanilla Bean Paste, is it teaspoon for teaspoon?

Tags: substitutions, vanilla

I would like to start using Vanilla bean paste in some of my recipes. I usually use Madagascar Bourbon Vanilla extract and wondered if the measurement was the same i.e. 1 teaspoon vanilla extract = 1 teaspoon vanilla bean paste. I thought I heard somewhere that the paste is a lot stronger. Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 11):

1 tbsp pure vanilla bean paste = 1 vanilla bean
1 tbsp pure vanilla bean paste = 1 tbsp vanilla bean extract

From experience I'd say the extract and the paste are equivalent in flavour.
The vanilla bean paste has the added texture of the seeds, which I prefer.

Of course neither of them leave you with a bean case to use as a garnish when your done creating!
We use both the paste and beans a lot!

[image: Source label on a jar of Madagascar Bourbon anilla bean paste -Nielsen-Massey (No association) here:]

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I wanted to know, pity that information wasn't on my bottle's label.